# About quadratic function and number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratics

If the vertex is above the straight line $$\{x\in\mathbb N, y = -4x+4\}$$ and the quadratic function with $(x-(n+1))^2-4n$ does not pass the (natural number, square number) point on the left side of the quadratic function, do there exist infinitely many cases where the quadratic function $$(x-(n-1))^2-4n+8$$ does not pass the (natural number, square number) point? Condition: $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Could you state your question more formally? I can't understand it

Comment: @CommandMaster I didn't put in one additional condition. The conditions are as follows: n is a natural number

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't provide much additional clarity. What do you mean by the "(natural number, square number) point"? When you say "quadratic function," are you talking about the Cartesian plot of the function (that is, those should be equal to $y$, which I think is what you want), or are you looking for something else?

Comment: what I am not getting is if $\{x \in \mathbb{N}, y = -4x + 4 \}$ then how can we call it straight line?

Comment: Some other questions: $1$. "If the vertex..." What vertex? $2$. "...the quadratic function with $(x-(n+1))^2-4n$..." Is $n$ a fixed value? $3$. Must it be the same value for $(x-(n-1))^2-4n+8$? $4$. "...do there exist infinitely many cases..." For infinitely many values of what?